# Does invertibility of a section $f$ (of a sheaf of rings) in every open set containing $x$ imply invertibility of $f$ in the stalk at $x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a sheaf of commutative rings on a topological space $X$.

Let a point $x \in X$ and a global section $f \in \mathcal{O}(X)$ be given.

Suppose that for every open $U \subset X$ with $U \ni x$
we have that $\mathrm{res}|^X_U(f)$ is invertible (a unit) in the comm ring $\mathcal{O}(U)$.

Then, does it hold that the germ of $f$ at $x$ is invertible in the stalk $\mathcal{O}_x$?

---

I guess a related question (but a stronger result) would be: is the set-of-invertible-elements functor $\mathrm{CommRings} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ a co-continuous functor?

---

Edit: as has been pointed out below, actually $f$ only needs to be invertible in at least one neighborhood $U$ of $x$, after which $f$ is then invertible in every open subset of $U$ since ring homomorphisms preserve invertible elements.

Thank you also to the very thorough answer below which explained how to get down to the level of stalks.

Comment: You only need this to happen in *one* neighborhood: [ring homomorphisms send units to units](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553550/ring-homomorphisms-map-units-to-units). (If this answers your question, please let me know so I can mark it as a duplicate.)

Comment: In fact, your condition is significantly stronger, as KReiser points out: $f$ is *globally* invertible if it meets the conditions that you specify.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize this point until now; I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Since ring homomorphisms preserve inverses, we see that if $fg = 1$ on $U$, then for each $V \subseteq U$ we have $(f \upharpoonright_V)(g \upharpoonright_V) = 1$ on $V$. It's not hard to show that this means $f_x g_x = 1$ in the stalk at $x$ by using the rule that we can compute products in the stalk by $[(f,V_1)] \ [(g,V_2)] = [(fg, V_1 \cap V_2)]$.

Another way to see this (which I mention mainly for cultural growth) is by using the internal language of the sheaf topos $\text{Sh}(X)$.

Indeed a sheaf of rings is "just" a ring object in this topos, and since $\top \vdash \exists! g . fg = 1$ is a [geometric sequent](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+theory), theorems in categorical logic immediately tell us that the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ has an inverse globally
2. $f$ has an inverse on each open set $U$
3. $f$ has an inverse at each stalk

For more information, see Ingo Belchschmidt's (excellent) PhD thesis [here](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf). In fact, this is an example given in chapter $1$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful and illuminating!